# context2d.strokeText() strokes the path under FF3.6/4

Tags: firefox, html, canvas

I am facing a strange effect with strokeText under FF (3.6 and 4beta4) that I don't reproduce under Chrome or Safari.
If I draw a filled path shape (but not stroked), and then a stroked text, the path is stroked when strokeText() is called.

Here is my code:

```
            var el = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            ctx = el.getContext('2d');

        ctx.save();
        // draw Rect
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 200);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill();

                    // draw Text
        ctx.save();         
        ctx.textAlign = 'start';
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.font = "bold 35pt sans-serif";
        ctx.strokeText("Hello World !", 100, 280);  

        ctx.restore();
```

If you run it, the rect is stroked in blue, while it should not.

Do you see something wrong with this code, or is it a bug in FF ?

Thanks !

Comment: did you try a ctx.beginPath()/ctx.closePath() before/after strokeText()?

Comment: You are right, it fixes the issue. Thanks ! (BTW, I upgraded to FF4beta8 and it is fixed. see my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It has been fixed in Firefox 4 beta 8. (just tested...).
I think the related bug is : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=499628

Answer (score 0):

What about drawing the rect in this way?

```
var el = document.getElementById('canvas'),
ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.save();
// draw Rect
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect  (100, 100, 100, 100); // <===
// draw Text
ctx.save();         
ctx.textAlign = 'start';
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.font = "bold 35pt sans-serif";
ctx.strokeText("Hello World !", 100, 280);  

ctx.restore();
```

**EDIT below** about strokeText problem, it seems that if you draw the text before drawing and filling the path fixes it

```
var el = document.getElementById('canvas'),
ctx = el.getContext('2d');

// draw Text -> at first
ctx.save();         
ctx.textAlign = 'start';
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.font = "bold 35pt sans-serif";
ctx.strokeText("Hello World !", 100, 280);

ctx.save();
// draw Rect
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(100, 200);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();

ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Indeed it fixes the issue, thanks. Unfortunately, this workaround breaks z-order (text may be hidden by other shapes). It seems something is wrong in FF canvas...

Comment: @Patrick Yeah, I think so.. btw, in your particular case, using the fillRect would be better :)

Comment: yes :-) But I was not telling all the truth ;-) I use dojox.gfx that wraps the canvas api. The code here is _roughly_ what gets generated.